# Strongly convergence in L^2

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

Let the sequence $(f_n(x,u))$  such as, for all $n,$ $f_n$ is Caratheodory, and $|f_n|\leq g$ where $g \in L^1(\Omega)$
Let $u_n \in H^1_0$ such as it is strongly convergent to $u$ in $L^2$ and a.e $\Omega$.
How we can use the Fatou lemma to prove that $f_n(x,u_n)u_n$ strongly converges in  $L^2$ to $f(x,u)u$ and a.e in $\Omega$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by $|f_n|\lt g$ (what are the arguments in both functions)?